# Why file glob expansion is not suppressed

Tags: shell, quoting, wildcards

I have the following script `my.sh`:

```
echo $@
```

Now I want to see file glob expansion, so I do like this and it works OK:

```
$ bash my.sh *
$ f1 f2 my.sh
```

Now, I've tried suppress expansion using techniques described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456496/2545680):

```
$ bash my.sh "*"
$ bash my.sh \*
```

But I still get listing of all files as the output. Why?

Comment: quote it `"$@"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the first invocation of your script

```
$ bash my.sh *
```

the file name globbing is performed by the shell before calling the script.

With the second invocation of your script

```
$ bash my.sh "*"
```

the file name globbing is performed in the script when running `echo $@`.

To avoid this, double quote `$@` on that line:

```
echo "$@"
```

Further reading: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: thanks, what about `bash my.sh \*`?

Comment: @Maximus That is the same as `bash my.sh "*"`.